# Why can't the negation be of the structure "$\exists, \exists$"

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Why is it that the negation of a proposition with the structure "for all ..., there exists ..." is always "there exists ..., such that for all ..."?

For example, the negation of the statement "$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists M \in  \mathbb{R}  s.t.$" is "$\exists \epsilon >0    s.t. \forall M \in  \mathbb{R}$".

Why can't the negation be "there exists ..., there exists ...", e.g. $\exists \epsilon > 0 s.t. \exists M \in \mathbb{R}$?

From my understanding, I believe that the $\exists \epsilon >0 s.t. \exists M > \mathbb{R}$ is still mutually exclusive to $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists M \in  \mathbb{R}  s.t.$, so I don't understand why that's not a possible negation.

Comment: It's not enough for a proposed negation to only be true where the original is false - it must also only be false where the original is true. You could say that in addition to being mutually exclusive, a condition and its negation also must exhaust the space of all possibilities.

Comment: "not for all $x$ $P(x)$" is the same as "there exists $x$ such that not $P(x)$, and "not there exists $y$ such that $Q(y)$" is the same as "for all $y$ not $Q(y)$", so "not for all $x$ there exists $y$ such that $R(x,y)$" is the same as ....

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider accepting the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 6):

**Axiomatic explanation**:

From a really top down view, there are two rules:

- The negation of the statement $\forall x: P(x)$ is the statement $\exists x: \neg P(x)$. This is sensible, because in order for a statement about **all** things to not be true, a single counterexample is enough. That is, if there exists at least one black sheep, the sentence "all sheep are white" is false.
- The negation of the statement $\exists x: P(x)$ is the statement $\forall x: \neg P(x)$. This again makes sense, because if there does **not** exist a thing with some property, then all neither thing must have its property. If there does not exist a living dodo bird, then all dodo birds are dead.

Using **only** these two rules, it should be clear that the negation of the statement $\forall a\exists b : P(a,b)$ is $\exists a: \forall b: \neg P(a,b)$. To show that this is true, start with the original statement, negated:

$$\neg(\forall a\exists b: P(a,b))$$

Now, use the first rule above, and this must equal

$$\exists a: \neg(\exists b: P(a,b))$$

Now, use the second rule above on the inner parentheses, and the rule gets us that $\neg (\exists b: P(a,b))$ is equivalent to $\forall b: \neg P(a,b)$. Substitute that into the original equation and you get

$$\exists a:\forall b: \neg P(a,b)$$

---

**Intuitive explanation**:

Take a more intuitively understandable statement. Say you have a room of 6 people, and you want to say that everybody in the room is married to someone else in the room. You would write that as $$\forall x\exists y: \text{married}(x,y)$$ correct?

Now, what is the negation of the statement? When, if you have a room of 6 people, is it **not** true that everyone in the room is married to someone else in the room?

Is it when there exists at least one pair of people that are not married to each other? Say I have, in the room, Anne who is married do Ben, and Charles who is married to Dianne. Then, the statement

> There exists $x$ and there exists $y$ such that $x$ is not married to $y$

is **true**, because I can set $x$ to Anne, and $y$ to Charles, and then $x$ is not married to $y$. Would you now say the original statement is therefore false?

Answer (score -2):

**This answer is wrong** (see the edit)

The statement $\exists x\ \exists y : P(x,y)$ is same as $\exists x \land \exists y : P(x,y)$.

So the negation should be $(\forall x, \nexists y :  \lnot P(x,y))$ or  $(\forall y, \nexists x :  \lnot P(x,y))$

I'll give a similar example with the same statement as given by 5xum. Say there are $3$ men $M,M_1,M_2$ and $3$ women $W_1,W_2,W_3$ in the room of which $M_1,W_1$ and $M_2,W_2$ are couples. $P$ be the property that they are married.

$\exists m\ \exists w : \lnot P(m,w)$ is true.

Now, $\forall m\ \nexists w\ :P(m,w)$ is false. So is $\forall w\ \nexists m\ :P(m,w)$

**Edit** : After the error being pointed out by @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost, I realized that both the existential quantifiers should be either changed to both universal quantifiers or both as "there does not exist". Because, we have in the statement $\exists x\ \exists y\ : P(x,y) \equiv \exists x,y\ : P(x,y).$ So the negation will be $\forall x,y\ : \lnot P(x,y)$ which **cannot** be equivalent to $\forall x\ \nexists y\ : \lnot P(x,y)$.

Or else, the negation can be done as $\nexists\ x,y\ : \lnot P(x,y) \equiv \nexists\ x\ \nexists\ y\ : \lnot P(x,y)$

Comment: $\exists x (\exists y(P(x,y))$ when negated is $\lnot(\exists x(\exists y (p(x,y))$ which is equivalent to $\forall x \lnot(\exists y(P(x,y)))$ which is equivalent to $\forall x(\forall y\lnot(P(x,y))$. What I just showed is **NOT** the same as $\forall x \not\exists y \lnot (P(x,y))$, you added an extra negation for no reason. Please fix you answer.

Comment: Why is it not the same?

Comment: What do you mean, "why is it not the same?"? I explained it in my comment, you added an extra negation: $\not\exists x \equiv \lnot(\exists x)$. In essence this is what you wrote: $\forall x \lnot (\exists y(\lnot (P(x,y))))$. Do you see the extra negation now?

Comment: But my statement isn't $\exists m\ \exists w\ : P(m,w)$. It is $\exists m\ \exists w\ : \lnot P(m,w)$.

Comment: This is what you wrote: "The statement $\exists x\ \exists y : P(x,y)$ is same as $\exists x \land \exists y : P(x,y)$.

So the negation should be $(\forall x, \nexists y :  \lnot P(x,y))$ or  $(\forall y, \nexists x :  \lnot P(x,y))$"  this whole thing is wrong!

Comment: Oh! My bad. Thanks for pointing it out. So I should make both the quantifiers as either $\forall$ or $\nexists$ but not one of it as $\forall$ and the other as $\nexists$. Got it @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost

Comment: Should I delete my answer if it might be confusing other seekers? Anyways there is one correct answer given above.